# Google DataFlow - fixed number of workers

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a step in a Google DataFlow where I want to pull data from an external rate-limited API. Is there a way to divide up the data evenly between a fixed number of workers in order to obey the rate limit? (Need to know the number of workers in order to divide the rate limit by that number).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this depends on whether the pipeline is running via the batch or streaming runner:

Batch: no direct control for this besides setting numWorkers and maxNumWorkers to the desired value.  This will affect the entire pipeline though, not just the stage where you want rate limiting

Streaming: The [UnboundedSource](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/UnboundedSource.java) API lets you specify precisely the number of parallel input splits you want with the `generateInitialSplits()` call.  Then, each split can obey its own local rate limit.

Comment: In my pipeline the API calls are the first step and probably also the slowest, so the batch method will probably work  without creating too many issues. I'll try that and see how it goes.